# Html added through jQuery('divname').html won't work with .click functions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a main wrapper html block that holds all of the needed jquery functions. Depending on what the user clicks,  an ajax call makes some calls and replaces the inner content div with the returned html.   Buttons in the newly places HTML aren't registering the .click functions from the wrapper html.  Clicking them does nothing.

Checking the source,  the jquery functions are still there,   so they aren't being removed or replaced.

Some code:

Here's a jquery function I'm using.  It check for a button click. If so,  it makes a call, then replaces the content div with the return html.  This new html will replace the html that contained the previous button,  but it will contain it's own button with the same id. This new button isn't registering it's clicks with the jquery function.

```
jQuery("#newhtml").click(function() {
    var ajaxurl = "urltogetnewhtml";
    new Ajax.Request(ajaxurl, {
        method: 'post',
        onComplete: function(transport) {
           jQuery('#content').html(transport.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

In other words,  it works the first time,  but not again. Click the button "New Html", replaces the content block with new html,  including a new button called "New Html".  This new button doesn't work, even though the jquery code is still there.

Comment: I am amazed that people post questions without providing code examples. We can only really help when we see the context please provide a Fiddle

Comment: Your code. Show us your code. I command thee! Hey shoe store, got any sandals? Do the sandals have souls in them? (google satan shoe store if you don't get the reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you click bindings look like?  If you are adding elements dynamically, you should use a delegated event.

For example:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function() { ... });
```

Is not going to work if you created #mybutton with .html().  Instead, use:

```
$('#static_container').on('click', '#mybutton', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

As the HTML is added dynamically, the .click function will not work. After adding the HTML, you need to call the function which defines the click again. You can use

```
$('#container').html(data);

$('#container').on('click', '.thumbnail', function(event){
 // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Click function won't work here. Use `jQuery.on()` function for binding events on element which are added after page load.
You can bind any event using this function. For more detail, visit : http://api.jquery.com/on/

while Click event is binded on the elements which are loaded on page load.

You can use :

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

or

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The handlers need to be reinitialized for new elements. Use [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in reference to the deprecated [jQuery .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) methods which will set event handlers for elements currently matching your selector and all future elements that match the selector. Or you can simply reinitiatilize your ahndlers however you are currently doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the "on" function of jQuery to bind the click.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

For example $("div.innerHTML").on("click",function(){})

"on" checks that a particular element exists on the page when the event takes place.

Answer (score 0):

Because you would have to recall the click() code to register it with the new items, It does not magically pick them up.

Better solution is to use `on()`

```
$("#wrapperId").on("click, ".childButton", function() { alert("foo"); } );
```